# Program to get a sorted list in increasing order of last element in each tuple in a given list using decorators

Tags: python

I try to get execute a program to get a sorted list in increasing order of last element in each tuple in a given list using decorators.

Here is my decorator:->

```
import functools
List2 =[]
List3 =[]
def parapassing_decorator(tuple1):
    def getSortedElement(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner1(*args, **kwargs):
            list2 = func(*args, **kwargs)
            output = [ q  for q in tuple1 for l in list2 if l == int(q[1],)]
            print(output)
        return inner1;
```

Now get the all last element from all tuples and sort it here

```
@parapassing_decorator(tuple1 = ([(2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1)]))
def getlastelements(tuple1):
    for t in tuple1:
        List2.append(t)
        List2.sort()
        return List2
```

now decorator is passing with getlastelements function to compare with all tuples  last elements and rearrange it in a list.
calling method:-

```
getlastelements(tuple1=[(2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1)])
```

But I got the error like:-

```
35 @parapassing_decorator(tuple1 = ([(2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1)]))
---> 36 def getlastelements(tuple1):
     37     for t in tuple1:
     38         List2.append(t)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: I don't know what else is wrong, but the `return` in `return List2.sort()` is useless and probably a mistake; `list.sort` sorts the `list` in place and returns `None`, not the sorted `list`, so your caller will receive `None`, not the sorted `List2`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger
 shall I return List2......this List2 will require  here :-list2 = func(*args, **kwargs) in the decorator I suppose.

Comment: Actually this list gives me all last element of tuple in a sorted order and then I take one by one and compare with all tuples. output = [ q  for q in tuple1 for l in list2 if l == int(q[1],)]

Comment: This might be the weirdest attempt at sorting I've seen. Why do you want to use a decorator here, and how do you intend to use this all (i.e., show some code using this)?

Comment: Why not just `sorted(list_of_tuples, key=lambda t: t[-1])` ?

Comment: (It would be really funny if you're only trying this with decorators because you heard of sorting with [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-decorate-sort-undecorate) :-)

Comment: Yes I want to use decorator here.My intend to do that a way :- getlastelements function will provide me all the last elements of tuples in a sorted manner then I can sort tuples with respect to that list.

Comment: This is an extremely strange program. Why are you passing the list twice, once to the decorator and once to the function when you call it? What's the purpose of the decorator? Is it supposed to be usable with other functions? This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223254), where you're asking about something very strange in the quest to achieve something that can be done much more naturally some other way.

Comment: Actually this lines gives me error :- def getlastelements(tuple1)....I suppose some problem with decorator declaration.

Comment: If you're getting an exception, please [edit] your question to include the full traceback. It's not clear from your post what is going wrong, so we are going to struggle to help you with it (thus the focus on the bigger picture).

Comment: Yes Mr. Blckknght I have noticed too.I have passed list  two times because getlastelements and decorator both needs list. May be my thinking is wrong . I suppose I arrange decorator function wrong here.let me rethink.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for trouble you all.
I think this solution is usable.

```
import functools

List2 =[]
List3 =[]

def parapassing_decorator(tuple1):
    @functools.wraps(tuple1)
    def inner1(func):
        list2 = func(tuple1)
        output = [ q for l in list2 for q in tuple1  if l == int(q[1],)]
        List3.append(output)         
        print(output)
    return inner1;      

@parapassing_decorator(tuple1 = ([(2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1)]))
def getlastelements(x):
    for t in x:
    List2.append(t[1])
List2.sort()
return List2
```